# React, Electron open app after installation(maybe postinstall)

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

Hello I have React App build with Electron. I would like to do 2 things after app installation:

1. Open app automatically
2. Write into file some kind of installationId(or manipulate with state(using **electron-store**))

I have been looking and can't find anything. Only have seen something like **postinstall**, but I don't have any knowladge how to use it. Maybe anyone can help me with this one?